# Rabbit MQ message deduplication

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Thanks for the forum replies and sharing.
Im looking for **deduplication** settings from **rabbit mq side**. Is it in the **queue side or exchange side** ?

Do we have a steps to configure **rabbit mq or queue or exchange **so that duplicated message will be discarded except one.
messages contain **id numbers **(simply, integer or numeric strings not any complex object)  , but some time from application, it sends from various entity listeners (**java /jpa**) on certain events and message duplication is certain and inevitable most cases.
we would like to store one message and process one out of the duplicated messages.
I'm looking for a feature in rabbit mq so that it takes care deduplication.

didn't find much details online.
If anybody know or explored this, can you point me that a link or type here how to.

Thanks in advance.
Sanal

** expecting some steps to configure in Rabbit mq side so that minimise logic/deduplication logic in Message publisher side.

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ does not support the deduplication using classic, quorum and stream queues.

The only deduplication is with Stream-Plugin and RabbitMQ stream clients.

See for example the [java documentation about that](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-stream-java-client/stable/htmlsingle/#outbound-message-deduplication)

See also this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Gsantomaggio/149b604113bf9d2e044a0f89531c101f) about stream and stream-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably a bit late.
But this plugin might be useful https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication

With it you can define message deduplication exchanges and post messages with a specific header which is checked for uniqueness.

Code snippet in ruby, using bunny gem:

```rb
queue = channel.queue('my-queue')
exchange = channel.exchange('my-exchange',
                 type: 'x-message-deduplication',
                 durable: true,
                 arguments: { 'x-cache-size' => 50, 'x-cache-persistence' => 'disk' })
queue.bind(exchange)

exchange.publish('ping', headers: { 'x-deduplication-header' => 'i' })
exchange.publish('ping', headers: { 'x-deduplication-header' => 'i' })
exchange.publish('pong', headers: { 'x-deduplication-header' => 'o' })
```

After execution the queue will contain 2 messages with content `ping` and `pong`

Comment: Katya Spasova, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: I added an example. Thanks for your feedback!